# How to create TCP socket on Robot to communicate with PC?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a new user of ROS. I'm trying to sending commend from a PC to a robot. The reason is that only my PC has a CUDA capable video card. My neural network program will run on the PC's GPU and send its output as the commend to the robot. My desktop is using Win7.

I know generally that I need to use TCP socket to let them communicate. But I don't know how to do that in detail. Can someone help me? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221305/how-to-create-tcp-socket-on-robot-to-communicate-with-pc?/) by [zxzhijia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25137/zxzhijia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just create a ROS client and Server and pass ROS messages between the two.  It will take care of all of the low level socket details.

look at the ROS tutorials for help on that

---

Originally posted by [Shawn Schaerer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23929/shawn-schaerer/) with karma: 106 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0